# Mongoengine, retriving only some of a MapField

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

For Example.. In Mongodb..

```
> db.test.findOne({}, {'mapField.FREE':1})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4fb7b248c450190a2000006a"),
    "mapField" : {
            "BOXFLUX" : {
                    "a" : "f",
            }
    }
}
```

The 'mapField' field is made of MapField of Mongoengine.
and 'mapField' field has a log of key and data.. but I just retrieved only 'BOXFLUX'..

this query is not working in MongoEngine....
for example..

```
BoxfluxDocument.objects( ~~ querying ~~ ).only('mapField.BOXFLUX')
```

AS you can see..
**only('mapField.BOXFLUX')**  or only **only('mapField__BOXFLUX')** does not work.
it retrieves all 'mapField' data, including 'BOXFLUX' one..

**How can I retrieve only a field of MapField???**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see there is a ticket for this: https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/508

Works for me heres an example test case:

```
def test_only_with_mapfields(self):

    class BlogPost(Document):
        content = StringField()
        author = MapField(field=StringField())

    BlogPost.drop_collection()

    post = BlogPost(content='Had a good coffee today...', 
                    author={'name': "Ross", "age": "20"}).save()

    obj = BlogPost.objects.only('author__name',).get()

    self.assertEquals(obj.author['name'], "Ross")
    self.assertEquals(obj.author.get("age", None), None)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
query = BlogPost.objects({your: query})
if name:
    query = query.only('author__'+name)
else:
    query = query.only('author')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my fault! I used `only` twice.

For example:

```
BlogPost.objects.only('author').only('author__name')
```

I spent a whole day finding out what is wrong with `Mongoengine`.

So my wrong conclusion was:

```
BlogPost.objects()._collection.find_one(~~ filtering query ~~, {'author.'+ name:1})
```

But as you know it's a just raw data not a `mongoengine` query.

After this code, I cannot run any `mongoengine` methods.

**In my case, I should have to query depending on some conditions.**

**so it will be great that 'only' method overwrites 'only' methods written before.. In my humble opinion.**

I hope this feature would be integrated with next version. Right now, I have to code duplicate code:

not this code:

```
query = BlogPost.objects()
query( query~~).only('author')
if name:
    query = query.only('author__'+name)
```

This code:

```
query = BlogPost.objects()
query( query~~).only('author')
if name:
    query = BlogPost.objects().only('author__'+name)
```

So I think the second one looks dirtier than first one.

of course, the first code shows you all the data 
using `only('author')` not `only('author__name')`