# Return a field in a subdocument

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Using mongoengine, how can I restrict my query so that one of the fields is a variable in a subdocument.

In other words, what is the equivalent of Mongo query

```
db.sample.find({ dataset: 'DATASET1' }, { 'dataset': 1, 'sampleid': 1, 'variables.Alb': 1 })
```

which returns a structure like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a398561d41c85904e58d81"),
    "dataset" : "DATASET1",
    "sampleid" : "ID1001",
    "variables" : {
        "Alb" : 0.09791
    }
}
```

I'd expect the mongoengine syntax to be something like

```
Sample.objects.filter(dataset='DATASET1')
.only('dataset')
.only('sampleid')
.only('variables.Alb')
```

Instead this yields an error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'db_field'`

What am I doing wrong? I see there's the also the option to do a `__raw__` query as well, but it does not accept an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had forgotten to define `variables` in the `Sample` schema definition. I thought this would be allowed since the document is `DynamicDocument`, allowing flexible schema. Also, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679458/mongoengine-retriving-only-some-of-a-mapfield), `variables__Alb` would also be legal in this case.